What are the Standards and The Best Practice In c?
i'm new here, i'm trying learn c and also i want to know the best practices to write good quality code and legible code, Thanks.
i'm tried search the standards and best practices in c but i didn't found anything yet, if you can response this i really glad with u.

That is a huge topic, much too broad for a Q&A site like this.

Here is a good set of standards published by Carnegie Mellon University.

Thanks for response to my answer, i really appreciate that.
